# the hitbox of an image doesn't change with "object-fit: contain"

Tags: html, css

I have a list of images that share the same vertical size. Unfortunately, some of these images are larger. I attempted to resize them using "object-fit: contain" and "max-width: 100%" to ensure they stay within the screen boundaries. However, there is a border around each image, and while the images fit the screen as intended, the hitbox and the border dimensions remain unchanged.

```
#conteneur_artistes img{
    height :55vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    border:#d5a926 4px ridge;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

I tried to use a media query, but I don't like this solution.